# Unable to patch class instantiated by the tested class using unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I am trying to patch a class that is instantiated by the class I am trying to test, but it doesn't work. I have read the various docs but still haven't found what I am doing wrong. Here is the code snippet:

In `tests/Test.py`:

```
from module.ClassToTest import ClassToTest

class Test(object):

    @mock.patch('module.ClassToPatch.ClassToPatch', autospec = False)
    def setUp(self, my_class_mock):
        self.instance = my_class_mock.return_value
        self.instance.my_method.return_value = "def"
        self.class_to_test = ClassToTest()

    def test(self):
        val = self.class_to_test.instance.my_method() #Returns 'abc' instead of 'def'
        self.assertEqual(val, 'def')
```

In `module/ClassToPatch.py`:

```
class ClassToPatch(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def my_method(self):
        return "abc"
```

In `module/ClassToTest.py`:

```
from module.ClassToPatch import ClassToPatch

class ClassToTest(object):
    def __init__:
        # Still instantiates the concrete class instead of the mock
        self.instance = ClassToPatch()
```

I know in this case I could easily inject the dependency, but this is just an example. Also, we use a single class per file policy, with the file named like the class, hence the weird import naming.

Comment: Try @mock.patch('module.ClassToTest.ClassToPatch', autospec = False)

Comment: In the future, please make your sample code an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); there were several bugs in your posted code and you can't rely on someone being familiar enough with the problem to immediately spot the issue and offer a solution.

Comment: Ok I will take note of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As norbert mentions, the fix is to change the mock line from

```
@mock.patch('module.ClassToPatch.ClassToPatch', autospec = False)
```

to

```
@mock.patch('module.ClassToTest.ClassToPatch', autospec = False)
```

[According to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide):

> The patch() decorator / context manager makes it easy to mock classes or objects in a module under test. The object you specify will be replaced with a mock (or other object) during the test and restored when the test ends.

You are testing the `ClassToTest` module, not the `ClassToPatch` module.

Comment: Im stuck with a somewhat similar situation. I need to patch a class instance instantiated in a different module. Is it possible?